# How can I replace "Process completed with exit code 1." with a custom error Annotation?

Tags: github-actions

I have `echo "::error title=Foo::Bar"` in one of my actions so that I can give a more descriptive error annotation than just "Process completed with exit code 1.", and this has the desired effect of adding an error annotation to the job and workflow with the given title and text. However, the "Process completed with exit code 1." is still also there, so I get two errors from every such job. If I exit with code 0 then the job status changes from red-x-mark to green-check-mark which is not what I want.

Is there a way to *only* replace the single error with my custom error, without changing the status of the job or having other side effects?

Example workflow code:

```yaml
name: test
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # TODO suppress default "Process completed with exit code 1." error
      - name: Error
        run: |
          echo "::error title=Foo::Bar"
          (exit 1)
```

Comment: I don't think you can override this message using shell alone, it seems be the default pattern when you use exit codes :/ [here is a reference for actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/setting-exit-codes-for-actions), but I couldn't find a doc for steps using shell commands.

Comment: The docs are here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-setting-an-error-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/actions/github-script exposes the ability to execute javascript against the Github api, including `core.setFailed`

```yaml
   - steps:
     - name: Foo
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          script: |
            core.setFailed('Custom error message')
```

This will result in the Foo step failing, with the corresponding red (X) icon and impact on later steps, without an extraneous exit code annotation.

Comment: And how to use it? Here is step with `run` in the question. `run` can't be used with `uses` in same step, so where `Foo` should be added? Is It should be added as a new step? After of before failed step? How it should be related with failed step at all? What if I want to set message `step {step_name} failed`? I can't see how `github-script` may be used within bash script

Comment: @rzlvmp this example replaces the bash script that produces an error output. If you have a script that does necessary work and also produces an error then you'd have to split that into two pieces and replace just the second piece.

Answer (score -1):

The exit message can be set by calling the [error command](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-setting-an-error-message):

```bash
echo "::error::Example Error Message!"
```

or with a file/line number:

```bash
echo "::error file=app.js,line=1,col=5,endColumn=7::Missing semicolon"
```

Comment: As described in the question, I was already using this command. This adds a new error, but does not change or eliminate the existing exit code error. Producing two errors every time is not desired.

Comment: My bad, I missed that!